# Simple app to identify video driver issues?

Tags: windows, video, drivers, graphics-card

I am the developer of a Flash-based web game and some of our users, who are non-technical, report that the game is running slowly for them.  While this could be for obvious reasons, such as running a computer that they bought during the Clinton era, I think some performance issues might be fixable.  For example, someone who has not installed their video drivers after reinstalling Windows might experience very poor performance and not know that they need to download and install drivers.

I am looking for a Windows program that I can point non-technical people to, and have them download and run it, and it will simply identify their video card and maybe just advise them on if their card's specific drivers are up to date or even installed at all.  It doesn't need to do everything -- I can probably write up a little tutorial to explain how to download drivers from each of the major card manufacturers, so I really just need a handy little, simple utility that will tell them if the video driver (or lack thereof) may need attention, and at least the type of card so I can tell them where to go.

I have looked at CPU-Z (from [cpuid.com](http://www.cpuid.com/)) and it is fairly simple and will at least identify the video hardware, but I'm not sure it looks at the existence of drivers.

Does anyone have some software suggestions for me to try?  Thanks!

Comment: it's not the video cards, it's the game platform... i think Adobe's trying to take over Microsoft's traditional mission of *"bloat the software until the user is forced to buy the latest hardware"* :)

Answer (score 1):

What about DXDIAG? Should be installed on any machine that has DirectX installed and does display driver information.